# System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm i am getting this error in my mvc3 project please help me to resolve this

here is my code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
}
@model FoodMart.Models.AccountModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{   
<div id="result" style="width:800px">    
<fieldset style="width:100%">
<legend><span style="font-size:larger; color:Green; font-family:Arial">Register Here</span></legend>
 <table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
 <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.users.FirstName,"Enter First Name")</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.users.FirstName, new { style = "width:150px" })</td>
 <td><span style="font-size:medium; color:Green;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.users.FirstName)</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.users.Landline)</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.users.Landline, new { style = "width:150px" })</td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>

 </table>
</fieldset>
</div>    
}
```

Comment: This is likely an error in your web.config, but it's impossible to tell without any code or markup whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

`AjaxHelper.BeginForm` is an extension method defined in the namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Ajax`.

Do you have this namespace defined in the `web.config` in your `Views` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting this instruction at the top of your view ?

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax
```